# Rendering WPF controls on planes in 3D space

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d, directx

I have the following setup: I can track a surface very accuratly in a 3d space using a tracking system. Now I want to project on this plane with an overhead projector.

I want to develop my interface in WPF/XAML and then render it in real time to the surface that is tracked. But I don't know exactly how to do it...

This is what I think: I need to model the tracked surface in a 3D space, then I want to develop the interface using regular WPF/XAML controls use (maybe) directx to render these controls to model in 3D that represent the tracked surface.

I already found information of using directx in combination with wpf (Sharpdx.WPF) but here they demonstrate how to create 3d scenes with wpf... However, they don't show how to use regular WPF controls and render these to the 3d models.

Do I first need to convert the user control of WPF/XAML to an image and then render it to the 3d model or is there another way to do it?